# how to search elements of list in another nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, nlp, nltk

```
verb_list=[['was', 'playing'], ['watches'], ['guesses'], ['washes'], ['are', 'enjoying'], ['enjoy', 'playing'], ['are', 'wearing'], ['were', 'throwing']]
```

verb_list list shows verbs of multiple sentences confined in it.

```
be_verb=['be','am','is','are','was','were','being']
```

be_verb list shows self-created auxiliary verb list.

I've to search "be_verb" elements in "verb_list" and create a separate list of singular and plural verbs wrt to each sentence.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner list comprehension

```
verbs = [verb[1] for verb in verb_list if verb[0] in be_verb]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for list in verb_list:
    for word in list:
        Current_word = word
        for verb in be_verb:
            Current_verb = verb
            if Current_word == Current_verb:
                print(Current_word, " is a verb to be")
            else:
                continue
```

Try this out

Comment: not giving any output.

Comment: How so? I tried it for myself and it worked perfectly fine

can you tell me what you did exactly? maybe provide a picture of the whole code